# "Unused goods" in the context of tax free shopping

Tags: shopping, hungary, tax-refunds

Goods should be unused with original packaging when getting a stamp from customs officers. After some googling, details remain unclear. I am looking in particular for Europe.

https://taxation-customs.ec.europa.eu/guide-vat-refund-visitors-eu_en does not specify if the item should be used or not, only a stamp is required.

> You will receive an invoice for the goods. You must show the invoice, the refund form, the goods and any other necessary documents to the customs officers of the last EU country you leave. The customs officers must stamp the form as proof of export. Without the stamp, you will not obtain the refund.

Global Blue states

> Obtain an import stamp on the Tax Free form from your local Customs within 3 months following the month when your form was issued. Please provide the Customs Authorities with your passport and unused purchased goods.

Global Blue Netherlands page states https://www.globalblue.com/tax-free-shopping/netherlands/

> Refunds are paid on goods that are exported in the traveller’s personal luggage.
> Only food, confectionary and medicine must be sealed and unused
> Non-refundable goods: Pictures made by a company as souvenirs

As I understand, to be on the safe side, item should be sealed, unopened and unused. With electronics, it is risky to do. It is safer to open the box and make sure item works as expected.

My friend went through Dutch customs with opened box of iPhone and got the stamp. I want to understand if that is a common practice in custom officers.

I will go through Hungarian customs with a similar situation. Is it really up to the custom officer who interprets the rule as they like?

Comment: You can't predict whether a customs officer will allow you to take something that is supposed to be unopened. If the item is new and unused and the seal is not broken you don't need to add additional sealed wrapping. If you "open the box and make sure it works" then it is not new and unused. Products do usually work, but opening and checking is no guarantee it will work in another country. So it is **safer** to leave unopened.

Comment: Your link does, however say: *Value added tax (VAT) is a multi-stage sales tax, the final burden of which is borne by the private **consumer**.* If a visitor does not **consum** (i.e use) the goods in the EU, then they are eligible for a refund of the VAT. If the Dutch customs had the impression that the iPhone had actually been used in the EU, then they would not have given the stamp.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I think interpretation of "consumption" of electronics is up to the officer here. I opened the iPhone in the apple store after sales clerk insisted it's safer to open it here to make sure item is not defective than opening it another country and deal with refunds later on. I think I'll see what happens at the Hungarian border.

Comment: @Halil did you get the stamp?

Comment: Good that you asked @PraneetRohida. Let me give an update of what happened.

Officer in Hungary asked me where do I go. I said, through Bulgaria I head to Turkey. He told me that I should get the stamp from there, even though I leave EU via Hungary. In Bulgarian customs, after a lot of trial and error, I found the person who is responsible for this. Person did not even check the box. She examined the receipt and duty free papers, then stamped it afterwards. 

tl;dr you get the stamp from last country that you leave from EU. Getting stamp depends heavily on the person.

Comment: @Halil Do not mix up the **Schengen Area** with the **EU Customs Union**. Not all members of the of the Schengen Area are in the EU, just as not all EU members are in the Schengen Area.